# Pandas Dataframe reshaping , by turning a column into column index, but keeping the rest of the column index intact

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe:

```
           Seq    Part    Type    Grand Total
   ------------------------------------------
    Q001   1      A       total     100
           1      A        ok        80
           1      A        not       20
           2      C       total     150
           2      C        ok       100
           2      C        not       50
```

I want it to be converted into:

```
           Seq    Part    total    ok      not
   --------------------------------------------
    Q001   1      A       100      80      20
           2      C       150     100      50
```

Meaning I want the values of Type column as column header and their associated values at Grand total in their respective columns, keeping the rest of DF intact.

I want to use tools like transpose/pivot for this instead of copying the whole thing bit by bit to another DF and create it as I wish.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would do it something like this (using `unstack`):

```
print df

      Q  Seq Part   Type  Grand_Total
0  Q001    1    A  total          100
1  Q001    1    A     ok           80
2  Q001    1    A    not           20
3  Q001    2    C  total          150
4  Q001    2    C     ok          100
5  Q001    2    C    not           50
```

For convenience I called your first column `Q` (if it is the index in your setup, reset the index):

```
df = df.set_index(['Q','Seq','Part','Type']).unstack(['Type'])
print df

              Grand_Total          
Type                 total   ok  not
Q    Seq Part                       
Q001 1   A             100   80   20
     2   C             150  100   50
```

I think this gets you what you want, but if you don't like the hierarchical column index then do something like the following:

```
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
print df.reset_index()  

Type     Q  Seq Part  total   ok  not
0     Q001    1    A    100   80   20 
1     Q001    2    C    150  100   50
```